# Qual a diferença entre Table e Matrix e List no Report View?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, wpf, relatório

Até o momento em meus relatórios venho usando tabelas e vinculo os meus *datasets* a essas. Porém hoje tive a necessidade de usar um `List` para criar um carnê (ainda estou tentando entender o seu funcionamento).

Quando usar Table, Matrix e List e suas diferenças?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/tables-matrices-and-lists-report-builder-and-ssrs):

## Tabela

É um relatório colunar. Ele funciona como uma matriz perfeita. É possível fazer algumas configurações, mas é aquele relatório clássico com linhas e colunas.

Hoje é como se fosse uma matriz limitada por configuração.

## Matriz

As principais diferenças são poder mesclar células e criar relações com outros dados, é como se tivesse uma tabela dentro de outra.

No fundo, nas versões atuais usa-se o [Tablix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/tablix-data-region-cells-rows-and-columns-report-builder-and-ssrs) que reúne o melhor das duas. É possível pegar configurações prévias para um modelo ou outro, mas é o mesmo mecanismo.

## Lista

Na verdade, deveria se chamar documento já que ele é livre para colocar os campos onde quiser.

Nova lista adicionada da caixa de ferramentas, selecionada
[image: Table, Matrix, List]

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).